# VertX EventBus not receiving messages in AWS context

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I have a Java service running on 3 different ec2 instances. They form a cluster using Hazelcast. Here's part of my `cluster.xml` configuration:

```
 <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"></multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="false"></tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="${AWS_ENABLED}">
            <iam-role>DEFAULT</iam-role>
            <region>us-east-1</region>
            <security-group-name>sec-group-name</security-group-name>
            <hz-port>6100-6110</hz-port>
        </aws>
</join>
```

Here's the log message that the discovery is successful:

```
[3.12.2] (This is the hazelcast version)
Members {size:3, ver:31} [
    Member [10.0.3.117]:6100 - f5a9d579-ae9c-4c3d-8126-0e8d3a1ecdb9
    Member [10.0.1.32]:6100 - 5799f451-f122-4886-92de-e351704e6980
    Member [10.0.1.193]:6100 - 626de40a-197a-446e-a44f-ac456a52d118 this
]
```

`vertxInstance.sharedData()` is working fine, meaning we can cache data between the instances.

However, the issue is when publishing messages to the instances using the vertx eventbus:

```
this.vertx.eventBus().publish(EventBusService.TOPIC, memberId);
```

and having this listener:

```
eventBus.consumer(TOPIC, event -> {
   logger.warn("Captured message: {}", event.body());
});
```

This configuration works locally, the consumer get's the messages, but once deployed to AWS it doesn't work.

I have tried setting up the host explicitly just for test, but this does not work either:

```
   VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
   options.setHAEnabled(true);
   options.getEventBusOptions().setClustered(true);
   options.getEventBusOptions().setHost("10.0.1.0");
```

What am I doing wrong and what are my options to debug this issue further?

Comment: are the firewalls/security groups of the ec2 instances set properly i.e. to allow incoming/outgoing on the eventbus and hazelcast ports ?

Comment: @AsadAwadia yes, the security groups are open to accept all traffic while testing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> eventbus communication does not use the cluster manager, but rather direct tcp connections
>
> > Quote from this conversation: https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/fCiJpQh66fk

The solution was to explicitly set the public host and port options for the eventbus:

```
    vertxOptions.getEventBusOptions().setClusterPublicHost(privateIpAddress);
    vertxOptions.getEventBusOptions().setClusterPublicPort(5702);
```